# How can I create and configure an Azure application registration using an Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, botframework

Is it possible to create and configure an Azure application registration using an Azure DevOps pipeline?

I'm working on setting up a bot from Microsoft Bot Framework 4.4+. Ideally, I'd like to be able to create all of the Azure resources (including the application registration) with a click of a button from Azure DevOps. I'd also like to be able to tear all those resources down with another click of a button.

This question is fairly straight forward, but I can't seem to find much documentation.

Answer (score 1):

One idea could be:

- Use an `Azure CLI task` (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-devops)) in your pipeline.
- Use the `az ad app create` CLI command (doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create)) in this task

Bots are Azure AD apps, you can find your existing ones using `az ad app list`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this could be to add a **Powershell task** to your pipeline.

Here is Microsoft Documentation on [adding a Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)

Then make use of **[`New-AzureRmADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.13.0)** or **[`New-AzADApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-2.0.0)**

```
New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication"
```

or

```
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication"
```